# How do I fix my custom function to work on dataframes that include non-numeric variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I have created the following function that converts a numeric column into proportions -

```
library(tidyverse)

my_function_2 <- function(data, var, round = 4){
    
    var_expr <- rlang::enquo(var)
    colnm_expr <- paste(rlang::get_expr(var_expr), "pct", sep = "_")
    
    data %>%
        mutate(!! colnm_expr := !!var_expr/sum(!!var_expr)) %>%
        round(round)
    
}
```

However it only seems to work if the dataframe has "only" numeric values. For example, it works for something like this -

```
mtcars %>% 
    count(cyl) %>% 
    my_function_2(var = n)

 cyl  n  n_pct
1   4 11 0.3438
2   6  7 0.2188
3   8 14 0.4375
```

However If use a dataframe that has a non-numeric column, I get an error, eventhough I'm trying to use the function on the numeric column -

```
# Sample dataframe
groups <- c("group 1", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5")
data   <- c(50000, 60000, 70000, 100000, 80000)
df <- tibble(groups, data)

# Test function on `data` column
df %>% my_function_2(var = data)
```

When I try the code above, I get the following error -

```
 Error in Math.data.frame(list(groups = c("group 1", "group 2", "group 3",  : 
  non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: groups
```

Seems like the error is telling me there are non-numeric variables in the dataframe. However I'm not sure why that is a problem since I am trying to use the function on the "data" variable which is a numeric column. How can I fix this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `round` is outside the `mutate`.  So, in the `mtcars` data, it wouldn't matter as the columns are all `numeric`, whereas in the created dataset, the 'groups' is `character`

```
round(df$groups)
Error in round(df$groups) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

We could make the changes in the function to `round` only the column of interest i.e. within the `mutate` itself

```
my_function_2 <- function(data, var, round = 4){
    
    var_expr <- rlang::enquo(var)
    colnm_expr <- paste(rlang::get_expr(var_expr), "pct", sep = "_")
    
    data %>%
        mutate(!! colnm_expr := !!var_expr/sum(!!var_expr) %>%
                            round(round))
    
    
    }
```

-testing

```
df %>%
    my_function_2(var = data)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  groups    data data_pct
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 group 1  50000    0.139
2 group 2  60000    0.167
3 group 3  70000    0.194
4 group 4 100000    0.278
5 group 5  80000    0.222
```